# Ошибка в файле mail.php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Разработал форму для отправки писем на почту посредством ajax и все бы ничего, но на почту приходит пустое письмо. Скрипт отправки js такой:

```
    $(".request__submit").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($('.request').valid()) {
        var dataForm = $(".request").serializeArray();
        var path = window.location.href;
        var path = path+'php/mail.php';
        console.log(dataForm);
        console.log(path);
        $.ajax({
            url: path,
            type: 'POST',
            data: dataForm,
            //dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Game over');
    }
});
```

Далее в работу включается скрипт mail.php

```
    $to = "evgeniy@gmail.com"; //Почта получателя, через запятую можно указать сколько угодно адресов
$subject = "Обратный звонок"; //Загаловок сообщения
$message .="<html><head><title>'.$subject.'</title></head><body>";
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key $value \r\n";
}                
$message .="</body></html>";
$headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
$headers .= "From: Отправитель <from@example.com>\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

На почту же приходит пустота, хотя в консоли все выводит:

```
Услуга Базовый сертификат 
name Иванушка 
Телефон +7 (965) 963-55-06 
E-mail jentos@mail.ru 
Наименование_организации Проверка 
Комментарий_к_заявке Комментарий 
Защищённый_носитель on 
Дистрибутив_СКЗИ_«КриптоПро_CSP»_на_CD_Формуляр on 
Установка_СКЗИ,_настройка_рабочего_места_для_работы_с_электронной_подписью_и_сопровождение_для_регистрации_в_ЕСИА_и_ГИС_ЖКХ on
```

Не знаю уже в чем проблема, вроде все верно, никаких ошибок, но в письмах пусто.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замени

```
echo "$key $value \r\n";
```

на

```
$message .="$key $value \r\n";
```

А то ты просто выводишь текст, в письмо он не попадает